# Devices not having the same SERVICE TYPE are getting discovered by my NSD app. What to do?

Tags: android, sockets

I was working on an app which uses Network Service Discovery (NSD) to find other android devices with the same app installed in them and connected to the same wifi network as my device. I pulled out the sample code from google and hence my app has a service type of `(_nsdchat._tcp)`.

My app uses a simple `TextView` to print the port number of the captured service (it being the other device having the same app) by calling `mService.getPort()`. But when I click connect after clicking Register Service (to get a socket no. for my device called the Host Port) and Discover Peers (to begin the `initializeResolveListener()`) the port number printed is not of the other device I want to connect to. I know this as I have installed my app on that other device too and it prints the host port number on clicking Register.

Also on clicking Discover Peers multiple times and then clicking Connect I get different port numbers printed on my UI.

Please guide me through this by telling me **what are those different port numbers which are getting printed?** And **how do i make my app connect to the other device having the same app only?**

I am providing the source code for the same. I intend to later establish a NSD connection between the two devices with the same app and transfer data so if anyone has prior experience with it please leave some heading in the answer.

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.anubhav.mapdemo;  

import android.content.Context;  
import android.net.nsd.NsdManager;  
import android.net.nsd.NsdServiceInfo;  
import android.os.Build;  
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;  
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.util.Log;  
import android.view.TextureView;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.ViewGroup;  
import android.widget.TextView;  

import java.io.IOException;  
import java.net.InetAddress;  
import java.net.ServerSocket;  

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)  
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     NsdManager.RegistrationListener  
{
     public static final String TAG="MapDemo.MainActivity";  
     int textsize=20;  
     NsdServiceInfo mService;  
     ServerSocket mServerSocket;  
     int mLocalPort;  
     public String mServiceName="NsdChat_AQ11";  
     public String SERVICE_TYPE="_nsdchat._tcp";  
     NsdManager mNsdManager;  
     NsdManager.RegistrationListener mRegistrationListener;  
     NsdManager.DiscoveryListener mDiscoveryListener;  
     public NsdManager.ResolveListener mResolveListener;  

@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

    //Context.NSD_SERVICE has been replaced by this.NSD_SERVICE as it was this which was being passed  
    // as context to begin with  
    mNsdManager = (NsdManager) this.getSystemService(this.NSD_SERVICE);  
    initializeResolveListener();  
    initializeDiscoveryListener();  
    initializeRegistrationListener();  

}  
   /* @Override  
   protected void onStart()  
   {  
       super.onStart();  



    }*/  
public void clickRegister(View v) throws IOException {  
    initializeServerSocket();  
    registerService(mLocalPort);  
    TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);  
    textView1.setTextSize(textsize);  
    textView1.setText("Host Port::"+mLocalPort);  

    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);  
    layout.addView(textView1);  
}  
public void clickDiscover(View v)  
{  
    mNsdManager.discoverServices(SERVICE_TYPE, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mDiscoveryListener);  
}  
public void clickConnect(View v)  
{  
    NsdServiceInfo service = mService;  

    if (service != null) {  
        Log.d(TAG, "Connecting.");  
        connectToServer(service.getHost(),
                service.getPort());  

    } else {  
        Log.d(TAG, "No service to connect to!");  
    }  
    TextView textView2=new TextView(this);  
    textView2.setTextSize(textsize);  
    textView2.setText("Peer Port::"+mService.getPort());  
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);  
    layout.addView(textView2); 
}  
public void connectToServer(InetAddress address, int port) {    
    //mChatClient = new ChatClient(address, port);  
}  
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)  
public void registerService(int port)  
{  
    NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo=new NsdServiceInfo();  
    serviceInfo.setServiceName(mServiceName);  
    serviceInfo.setServiceType(SERVICE_TYPE);  
    serviceInfo.setPort(port);  

    //mNsdManager = Context.getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);  
    mNsdManager.registerService(serviceInfo, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mRegistrationListener);  

}  

//gets any available port for the app, passing 0 as the argument helps generate default port number whichever available  
public void initializeServerSocket() throws IOException {

    mServerSocket = new ServerSocket(0);
    mLocalPort = mServerSocket.getLocalPort();
}
public void initializeRegistrationListener() {
    mRegistrationListener = new NsdManager.RegistrationListener()

    {
        public void onRegistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {

            mServiceName = serviceInfo.getServiceName();
            //  mServiceName = NsdServiceInfo.getServiceName();
        }

        public void onUnregistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onUnregistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {

        }

        public void onServiceRegistered(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {

        }

        public void onServiceUnregistered(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {

        }
    };
}
public void initializeDiscoveryListener() {

    // Instantiate a new DiscoveryListener
    mDiscoveryListener = new NsdManager.DiscoveryListener() {

        //  Called as soon as service discovery begins.
        @Override
        public void onDiscoveryStarted(String regType) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service discovery started");
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo service) {
            // A service was found!  Do something with it.
            Log.d(TAG, "Service discovery success" + service);
            //if (!service.getServiceType().equals(SERVICE_TYPE)) {
            if (!service.getServiceType().equals(service.getServiceType())) {
                // Service type is the string containing the protocol and
                // transport layer for this service.
                Log.d(TAG, "Unknown Service Type: " + service.getServiceType());
            } else if (service.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName)) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Same machine: " + mServiceName);
            } else if (service.getServiceName().contains("NsdChat")){
                mNsdManager.resolveService(service, mResolveListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceLost(NsdServiceInfo service) {
            // When the network service is no longer available.
            // Internal bookkeeping code goes here.
            Log.e(TAG, "service lost" + service);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDiscoveryStopped(String serviceType) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Discovery stopped: " + serviceType);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Discovery failed: Error code:" + errorCode);
            mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Discovery failed: Error code:" + errorCode);
            mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);
        }
    };
}
public void initializeResolveListener() {
    mResolveListener = new NsdManager.ResolveListener() {

        @Override
        public void onResolveFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
            // Called when the resolve fails.  Use the error code to debug.
            Log.e(TAG, "Resolve failed" + errorCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceResolved(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Resolve Succeeded. " + serviceInfo);

            if (serviceInfo.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName)) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Same IP.");
                return;
            }
            mService = serviceInfo;
            int port = mService.getPort();
            InetAddress host = mService.getHost();
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onRegistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {

}

@Override
public void onUnregistrationFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {

}

@Override
public void onServiceRegistered(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {

}

@Override
public void onServiceUnregistered(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {

}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.anubhav.mapdemo.MainActivity">



<Button
    android:text="Register Service"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="clickRegister"/>

<Button
    android:text="Discover Peers"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="clickDiscover"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:text="Connect"
    android:onClick="clickConnect"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```